# How to increase exim default message body size?

Tags: exim, centos7

i have following router and i want to increase default exim `message_body` size, now i have read that if we use this variable `message_body_visible` we can increase the default body size.

This is my router

```
runscript:
        driver = accept
        transport = run_script
        unseen
        no_expn
        no_verify
        message_body_visible = 2000
```

Now when i try this as follows i get an error

```
    Starting Exim: 2015-11-16 04:47:29 Exim configuration error in line 318 of /opt/afterlogic/etc/exim.cnf:
  option "message_body_visible" unknown
```

now can any help me, if i can use this variable here? or there is some other way to do it?

Comment: It seems you are adding it in the wrong section (acl). Try instead to put  it in main config area.

Comment: @bangal: check now its now only in router, previously i place it in both places i.e in ACL and router as well

Comment: Not even in router section. Put it somewhere near the begining, or post your full conf file.

Comment: You do know that `message_body_visible` is only used to determine how much of the body is returned in case of a permanent delivery error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exim configuration file has 3 parts, each performing it's separate functionality i-e ROUTERS, TRANSPORT and AUTHENTICATION. Sometimes, we need to do some additional settings and exim configuration file have a separate section for these. In your case there is nothing to do with the router. The fourth part I am talking about is the whole area of the file starting from the beginning and ending at the ROUTER section. Just write `message_body_visible = 'your_length'` anywhere above ROUTERS section. This will definitely solve the problem.